# How to avoid `modal-backdrop hide` insert to ionic cache?

Tags: angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

I encounter the problems of `modal-backdrop hide`keep append in my ionic view.
I need to call `modal` for my code. In my case, if the students click to the button check the answer then the modal of marking status will comes out.

However, If I repeatedly answer a lot of questions, the `modal-backdrop hide` append everytime I click the button.

Is it anyway to clear the cache for the `modal` like in `<ion-view cache-view="false"></ion-view>`?

[image]

Comment: What version of ionic are you using? I think this issue was fixed in an updated version

Comment: V1.3. ionic 1..How to solve this?

Comment: There are several 1.3.X versions. Which of them in particular?

Comment: Version ionic v1.3.1

Comment: Thought you were referring to the click-blocks. Can you share the code you use to show the modal? I'm guessing you're creating a new modal in scope everytime. This will definitely cause a memory leak

Comment: I got the answers...I forgot to use `$scope.modal.remove()`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ionic modal remove instead of hide.. Refer this Ionic Documentation.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/

Comment: Owh good answers! I forgot to use the `$scope.modal.remove();`